# Sapphire Nitro+ RX580 8GB Hynix Low hashrate?

Tags: cryptography

I've got Sapphire Nitro+ RX580 8GB [Hynix memory] and it hashes on 21.9 mh/s out of the box without any overclocking or bios modding, as far as I know it should be higher around 24 mh/s, any ideas why?

Answer (score -1):

21.9 is the correct hash for that 580 without strapping or overclocking.

Comment: It might help to say why its correct